# Getting deadlock with foreach and await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call a service, but the service has a max length per request, so I am splitting my request into multiple smaller requests.

I am then trying to to use HttpClient together with Await as its async

```
public async Task<string> CallGenoskanAsync(List<string> requestList)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userId, password);

        var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (string requestString in requestList)
        {
            using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials })
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestString).Result)
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        tasks.Add(content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        var result = "";

        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            result += task.Result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This code deadlocks when await client.GetAsync is called, it never finishes.

If I change that line to

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestString).Result)
```

Then I dont get any deadlocks, I suppose I am using await improperly together with foreach, but I can not figure out how

**Edit: Changed example code**

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will give you a warning for the code you posted; in particular, it will point out that `CallGenoskanAsync` is synchronous, not asynchronous.

The core problem is this line:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

[When you're writing asynchronous code, you shouldn't block on it. To do so can cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain in my blog post. The deadlock occurs because `await` will capture a "context" that it uses to resume execution of the `async` method. This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` or `TaskScheduler.Current`, and many contexts (UI and ASP.NET request contexts in particular) only allow one thread. So, when your code blocks a thread (`Task.WaitAll`), it's blocking a thread in that context, and this prevents the `await` from continuing since it's waiting for that context.

To fix, make your code asynchronous all the way. As I explain in my `async` intro post, [the asynchronous equivalent of `Task.WaitAll` is `await Task.WhenAll`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html):

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`WhenAll` also has the nice property that it unwraps the results for you, so you don't have to use the problematic `Result` property:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
return string.Join("", results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Relevant context is not provided:

**If**

1. Your code sample is part of a callstack that returns a Task
2. There is a blocking wait at the root of the callstack (e.g.,
   `DoSomething().Result` or `DoSomething.Wait()`)
3. You have a `SynchronizationContext` that's thread affinitized (IE, this is running pretty much anywhere but a Console application)

**Then**

Your synchronization context's thread may be blocked on the root Result/Wait(), so it can never process the continuation that the completed call to GetAsync() scheduled to it. Deadlock.

If you meet the above conditions, try applying .ConfigureAwait(false) to your awaited GetAsync. This will let the continuation get scheduled to a Threadpool thread. Be aware that you are potentially getting scheduled to a different thread at that point.